# PowerShell classes with Polymorphism and Singleton patterns

Tags: powershell, polymorphism, singleton

I am trying to implement a class that uses Polymorphism and Singleton patterns. The ultimate goal is a number of child classes that process different kinds of XML files when the child classes are instantiated, based on a passed array of files to process, and then store the combined and manipulated XML for later reuse. There are a number of methods that are common to all or most of the child classes (loading an individual XML file and checking its validity, checking to see if the XML is signed in certain situations, etc.) so it makes sense for those methods to be in there parent class. There will also be unique methods for each child class. And I want each child class to be a singleton, because there could be a lot of XML files to process, and there will be hundreds of references to the processed XML, so I want to do the loading and processing only once.
I am getting my basic understanding of PowerShell OOP from [this](https://xainey.github.io/2016/powershell-classes-and-concepts/#polymorphism) blog post.

This is what I have now to validate the patterns, and it "works", but it seems to me that the Singleton Methods are going to be common to all the child classes, so really should be in the parent class, but they also require implementation with the child class type, not the parent class type. Is there a mechanism to move these methods to the parent class, but have the parent class be aware of the type of child class making the call? Other than simply including the child class type as an argument?

```
class ParentClass {
    # Properties
    [collections.arrayList]$Files = [collections.arrayList]::New()

    # Methods
    [void] ListFiles() {
        Write-Host "Processed Files:"
        foreach ($processedFile in $this.Files) {
            Write-Host "$processedFile!"
        }
    }
}

class ChildClass : ParentClass {
    # Properties
    static [ChildClass] $instance

    # Constructor
    ChildClass([string[]]$filePaths){
        foreach ($fileToProcess in $filePaths) {
            $this.Files.Add("$($fileToProcess): Processed ($(Get-Date))")
            Start-Sleep -s:1
        }
    }

    # Singleton Methods
    static [ChildClass] GetInstance() {
        return [ChildClass]::Instance
    }
    static [ChildClass] GetInstance([string[]]$filePaths) {
        if ([ChildClass]::Instance -eq $null) {
            [ChildClass]::Instance = [ChildClass]::New($filePaths)
        }

        return [ChildClass]::Instance
    }
}

CLS
$unprocessedFiles = @('C:\file1', 'C:\file2', 'C:\file3')
$firstInstance = [ChildClass]::GetInstance($unprocessedFiles)
$firstInstance.ListFiles()
Start-Sleep -s:5
$secondInstance = [ChildClass]::GetInstance()
$secondInstance.ListFiles()
```

I had hoped that `GetType()` might help, since `$this.GetType()` in the parent class does return the child class type, but both of these fail...

```
static [$this.GetType()] GetInstance() {
}
static [$($this.GetType())] GetInstance() {
}
```

as does setting a property in the parent class and using that as the type like this...

```
$type = $this.GetType()
static [$type] GetInstance() {
}
```

I also tried this with and without wrapping in `()` and `$()`, as well as with and without the `[]` type marker.

```
[$this.GetType().ToType()] GetInstance() {
}
```

Also, as implemented I will probably want to throw an exception if the first GetInstance doesn't include the file paths array, as well as any subsequent GetInstance that does. But that seems clumsy, and I wonder if there is a better way to implement this? Or does it just perhaps seem clumsy to me because I am still getting used to the idea of overloading for every permutation of arguments?

Comment: I do like using a good [software design pattern](https://www.automatedops.com/blog/2018/04/11/software-design-patterns-in-powershell-strategy-pattern/) to solve a problem, but in my experience trying to use the static-typed OOP practices in PowerShell is counterproductive and I try to stick to idiomatic PowerShell. Most PowerShell projects don't need that level of abstraction and PowerShell Classes have limited functionality that you'll constantly have to fight.

Comment: @logicaldiagram I would love to hear what issues you feel will be an issue. I am refactoring about 15K lines of code, and thus far Classes seem to be a god send compared to Functions. I have the sense it is going to do wonders for maintainability and extendability, both of which I have struggled with over the years.

Comment: You can very easily compile C# at runtime in PowerShell so once you get beyond some basic use cases, like what you're attempting, it's usually much easier to build types in C# and consume them in PowerShell. 

You can't define Interfaces in PS and you will even run into issues implementing some C# interfaces. You don't get member access modifiers. Testing can be challenging since you can try to update a type, but in reality, the definition won't change in the current PS runspace. 

I agree that 15k lines in functional PowerShell is difficult to do without code duplication.